# Why I cant fetch item from mongodb when I add item with user.email?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I add item in MongoDB with user email . Because when a user login I can show which item he/she select .

so it shows it individually . But when I try to fetch them with others items selected by other user. it didn't fetch .

Comment: maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send your email address through query like
const url = `https://abc.xyz/"your server api route"?email=${email}`;
then get this email in server side by const email=req.query.email;
finally send response from server as per system by finding data by this email. hopefully you will get your desired items by email.

Comment: implenting by this method it shows users add item . but the items not adding with the remaining preious items